# Nginx - 4021#0 - Problems setting up

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

-I'm using a virtual machine with Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
-I'm doing a Django project with Uwsgi + nginx
-I added "192.168.33.50  myproject.com" to my hosts file
-I started uwsgi + supervisor + nginx process

-When I'm trying to access to myproject.com, I'm getting this error in /var/log/nginx/error.log:

> 2013/11/13 07:43:21 [crit] 14741#0: *1 connect() to
>   unix:/tmp/uwsgi_myproject.sock failed (2: No such file or
>   directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.33.1, s$

---

*Edition 1*
This is my uwsgi.ini:

> [uwsgi]
>
> module = myproject.wsgi:application
>
> master workers = 3
>
> logto = /vagrant/log/uwsgi.log 
>   socket = /tmp/uwsgi_myproject.sock 
>   pidfile = /tmp/uwsgi_myproject.pid chmod-socket = 666
>
> auto-procname need-app vacuum

---

*Edition 2*
If I execute this command in console:

> uwsgi --ini /vagrant/uwsgi.ini --chdir /vagrant/myproject/ --socket
>   /tmp/uwsgi_myproject.sock --pidfile /tmp/myproject.pid

With that command, uwsgi starts and I can access to myproject.com but it's supossed that uwsgi starts with supervisor of django

---

*Edition 3*

This is myproject.conf in /etc/nginx/conf.d/

> server {
>       listen 80;
>       charset utf-8;
>       sendfile off;
>
> ```
> # ONIX files
> client_max_body_size 100M;
>
> location /media/imagen {
>     include     uwsgi_params;
>     #The uwsgi_pass must comply with the details in supervisord.conf
>     uwsgi_pass  unix:/tmp/uwsgi_myproject.sock;
> }
>
> location /media/resources/protected {
>     root /vagrant/myproject/myproject;
>     internal;
> }
>
> location /media  {
>     root /vagrant/myproject/myproject;
> }
>
> location /static {
>     root /vagrant/myproject/myproject;
> }
>
> location / {
>     include     uwsgi_params;
>     #The uwsgi_pass must comply with the details in supervisord.conf
>     uwsgi_pass  unix:/tmp/uwsgi_myproject.sock;
>   uwsgi_read_timeout  300;
> }
> ```
>
> }

---

**EDITED: ADDED SUPERVISOR.CONF ASKED BY @ChrisC**

```
[supervisord]
logfile={{ PROJECT_DIR }}/../log/supervisord.log
pidfile=/tmp/supervisor_PROJECTNAME.pid
user=PROJECTNAME
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8,LC_LANG=en_US.UTF-8

[unix_http_server]
file = /tmp/supervisor_PROJECTNAME.sock

[program:__defaults__]
directory={{ PROJECT_DIR }}
startsecs=5

[program:autoreload]
exclude=true

[program:uwsgi]
command=uwsgi --ini {{ PROJECT_DIR }}/../uwsgi.ini --chdir {{ PROJECT_DIR }} --socket /tmp/uwsgi_PROJECTNAME.sock --pidfile /tmp/uwsgi_PROJECTNAME.pid
stopsignal=INT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the configuration of the supervisor. The supervisor wasn't loading the uwsgi process well.

Comment: Willing to share your uwsgi.conf for supervisor?